# How Do I pass a value in a input box, to another input box

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass values between boxes.

So, When a User types inside of the first text box:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your personal message" id="valbox"></input>
<input type="submit" name="design1" id="butval" value="Choose Design"></input>
```

Then they click the 'choose design' button, and what they typed in, gets passed to another
input text box on the same page.

this is the second input box i want to pass it to.

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" placeholder="" value="">
```

Any help would be much appreciated
thank you

Comment: so what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akDDQ/)**</kbd>

Instead of a `submit` type input use a `button` type input.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your personal message" id="valbox"></input>
<input type="button" name="design1" id="butval" value="Choose Design"></input>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" placeholder="" value="">
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('butval').onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('billing_last_name').value = document.getElementById('valbox').value;   
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. I had to finish up some code, and my javascript is horrible if you can't tell

Answer (score 0):

First add a clicklistener for the submit button and inside that callback pass the text through the elements

```
document.getElementById("butval").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var text = document.getElementById("valbox").value;
    document.getElementById("billing_last_name").value = text;
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is by far easiest in jquery given

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your personal message" id="valbox"></input>
<input type="submit" name="design1" id="butval" value="Choose Design"></input>

<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" placeholder="" value="">
```

use a simple

```
$("#butval").click(function(event){
    $("#billing_last_name").html("<p>"+$("#valbox").html()+"</p>");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

but better change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` then you can remove the essentially unnecessary line `event.preventDefault();`