# How to pass value in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have code like this :

```
<input type="text" name="txt_abc" size="5" maxlength="2">
```

And i want take value from `txt_abc` to this code

```
<input type="text" name="txt_cde" size="5" maxlength="2" value="value from txt_abc">
```

Can I use function `onChange()` or other way?

Edit: The code is in one `jsp file`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690117/how-do-i-pass-a-value-in-a-input-box-to-another-input-box and many others. Google `javascript pass input value to another input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different input events are available. For your case I prefer to use three events

1. **onfocus**
2. **onkeydown**
3. **onkeyup**

I used **onfocus** event to handle the scenario when user doesn’t type anything but **paste something into the first text** field.

Below is the sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction(){
 document.getElementById('txt_cde_Id').value = document.getElementById('txt_abc_id').value;   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="txt_abc" size="5" maxlength="2"  onfocus="myFunction()"  onkeydown="myFunction()" onkeyup="myFunction()"  id="txt_abc_id"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt_cde" size="5"  maxlength="2" value="value from txt_abc" id="txt_cde_Id"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you.